# Using ffmpeg to cut up video at multiple points

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that is a football game. I would like to cut the time `before the game`, `during half time` and finally the end of the game.

Total Clip Length `1h 51m` or `111m`

Ideally the cuts and time are as follows:

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| Start Time | Finish Time |    Clip Duration    |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1:30       |   47:30     |  47:30              |
| 53:00      |   100:00    |  47                 |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

However my video finishes at

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:30 -i Tripod_Camera.mp4 -t 00:47:30 -ss 00:53:00 -t 00:47:00 -c copy VideoClip.mp4
```

Comment: have you consider using a tool such as `LosslessCut` to perform this task? See [this reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/extract-clips-video-losslesscut/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=07092020)

Comment: @24601 ffmpeg can do this perfectly, and the command given indeed does that losslessly. It is a matter of finding the correct command options to do it in one go.

Comment: @vanadium ye correct. I just don't know when or how! :/

Comment: How accurate do you need the cuts to be? Because if you can accept cutting only on keyframes then you can do this without re-encoding. Refer to [Checking keyframe interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/) to see keyframe frequency.

Comment: It doesn't need to be tight at all actually. Considering I've allot of lea way on either side of the times. Its more that I could not work out how to pass `2 cuts` as it were to one FFMPEG command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make `input.txt` containing the timestamps (in seconds) to cut:

   ```
   file 'input.mp4'
   inpoint 90
   outpoint 2850
   file 'input.mp4'
   inpoint 3180
   outpoint 6000
   ```
2. Run `ffmpeg` to concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
   ```

- This will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy), so no re-encoding occurs meaning the whole process will be fast and quality will be preserved. However, cuts will be made on keyframes, so it may not be accurate enough. If greater accuracy is needed you'll have to use a much slower method such as using the (a)trim, (a)setpts, and concat filters which requires re-encoding.
- If you get A/V desync then [get timestamps of keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/), use keyframe timestamps as your `inpoint`, but add 0.001 to each `inpoint` timestamp in `input.txt`.

Comment: Thank you :D This does work perfectly! I have to ask, does it have to be a file? Or could I do it directly in the terminal?

Comment: @JamieHutber Kind of. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Videocut](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) which I've written for this purpose. Due to its own muxer it is more precise than ffmpeg and provides your with a graphical interface.

Since it is based on ffmpeg (or its libraries) the cutting is lossless.
[image]